# Delegation issue in SplitView Controller

Tags: ios, delegation

I am implementing one simple delegation between the Master and Detail views (Landscape orientation so both views are visible) in a SplitViewController. When I press a button, the table view in Detail should update.

Here is the declaration in 
MasterViewController.h

```
@protocol DetailVCDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)requestTableUpdate;
@end
@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
- (IBAction)updateTable:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <DetailVCDelegate> delegate;
```

in MVC.m i Do the following for the IBaction updateTable:

```
[self.delegate requestTableUpdate];
```

Then in the Detail.h

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController <DetailVCDelegate>
```

And in the Detail.m

```
- (void)requestTableUpdate
{
    NSLog(@"called");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The log is never called, nor the update for the tableView.
I would appreciate any suggestions of how to fix this, i guess I am missing some delegation rule that is specific for SplitViews

Comment: Do you ever actually _set_ the `delegate` property? In your IBAction, log on `self.delegate` and see what it is. I'm betting it's nil, in which case sending it the `requestTableData` will naturally do nothing.

Comment: Yep, its nill @matt , where should I set the delegate, I am still a bit confused about all the delegation pattern.

Comment: Make a new Master-Detail project (to get the pure template code) and look at how the delegate is set in AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a message to something and nothing happens, your first thought should be: hmm, maybe I'm sending a message to nil.

So, you say:

```
[self.delegate requestTableUpdate];
```

But nothing happens. So you should immediately check to see whether `self.delegate` is nil.

You have a declared a delegate *property*:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <DetailVCDelegate> delegate;
```

But a property has no *value* until you give it one. It is up to *you* to set the `delegate` property of your MasterViewController instance to some other instance (of something that adopts the DetailVCDelegate protocol, obviously). Delegates are not born: they are made, deliberately.